# get checksum of files inside tar archive on remote host

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, tar, md5sum

I succeed to obtain the md5sum of files inside archive without using file system thanks to :

```
tar tjf '/home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2' | sort | grep -v '/$' |
( while read filename;
    do md5=$(tar xjOf '/home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2' $filename | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'); 
    echo "$md5  $filename";
done)
```

Unfortunately what I need is to do on a remote host over ssh like :

```
ssh 192.9.202.44 tar tjf '/home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2' | sort | grep -v '/$' |(  while read filename; do md5=$(tar xjOf '/home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2' $filename | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'); echo "$md5  $filename"; done)
```

But like that it doesn't work, one of the tar command is interpreted locally and give me such error :

```
tar (child): /home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2 : no such file
```

Please , is somebody can tell me how to proceed?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass to ssh the commands to be executed remotely as one string:

```
ssh 192.9.202.44 "tar tjf '/home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2' | sort | grep -v '/\$' |(  while read filename; do md5=\$(tar xjOf '/home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2' \$filename | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'); echo "\$md5  \$filename"; done)"
```

Also, make sure characters like `$`, which are interpreted by the local shell, are quoted.

The longer the script gets, the easier to make a mistake doing all this quoting. It can be easier to write a 'normal' shell script, copy it to the remote host with `scp`, and then execute with `ssh`.

Comment: Great! Hours that i was trying to succeed and you did in 5 minutes. Thank you so much for adaptations. I tried to quote the whole command but not to escape $ characters, that was the trick. SOLVED!

Comment: I was doing something similar couple of weeks ago, so I knew all the traps very well :) Glad I could help. Do you mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest and fastest solution:

```
ssh 192.9.202.44 "tar --to-command=md5sum -xvjf /home/adup/mybackup.tar.bz2 | paste - -"
```

this should produce output like:

```
plik_1 21576a19c7e336a86b6f37578a1b9f4d  -
plik_2 90811da0150573efaba9c9d6aa1c4ea2  -
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As the last version didn't get rid of the folders, here a slightly different approach for a local and remote archive:

local archive:

```
tar --to-command=md5sum -xvf 20180405181352.tar |grep -v /$ | paste - - > md5sum_local.txt
```

remote archive:

```
ssh user@host "cat /path/myfile.tar" | tar --to-command md5sum -xvf - | egrep -v /$ | paste - - > md5sum_remote.txt
```